# I am trying to do conditional form validation using Yup But am Unable to Change the value of value "showfile"

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am using formik and Yup to handle by form data and Form Validation in react . I am trying to change the value of "Showfile" to true to do conditional validation But value is not changing.

```
                             

                                    
                                    TextField
                                    label="Resume"
                                    star="*"
                                    color="red"
                                    name="file"
                                    type="file"
                                    accept=".pdf ,.docx,.doc "
                                    onChange={(event) =>
                                        formik.setFieldValue(
                                            "file",
                                            event.currentTarget.files[0],
                                            "showfile",
                                            true
                                        )
                                    }
                                    value={formik.value}
                                />
```

```
file: Yup.mixed().when("showfile", {
            is: true,
            then: Yup.mixed()
                .required("Required")
                .test(
                    "FILE_SIZE",
                    "Uploaded file is too big.",
                    (value) => value && value.size  value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type)
                ),
```

```
Formik
            initialValues={{
                UserName: "",
                email: "",
                Phone: "",
                message: "",
                file: "",
                showfile: false,
                submit: false,
            }}
            validationSchema={validate}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(values);
                    actions.setSubmitting(false);
                }, 1000);
            }}
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `setFieldValue` wrong way. It only updates for one field. If you want set 2 filed, you need to call `setFieldValue` 2 times:

```
onChange={(event) => {
    formik.setFieldValue("file", event.currentTarget.files[0]);
    formik.setFieldValue("showfile", true);
}}
```

You can read more about `setFieldValue` in here: https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void

Comment: ok.. that got resolved but now i am getting required error message just after selecting accepted file .... and on clicking other field it is disappearing.....

Comment: what should be the value of file field... here i have given value={formik.values.file}

Comment: I think you need to add another answer with the detail about your problem. After that, I can take a look and maybe can help you

Comment: Thank u for your help... that problem got resolved ... I am facing a new problem in validating my file field using Formik and Yup.... I have posted my question here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67323291/i-am-getting-validation-error-even-after-selecting-right-file-type-i-am-using